# Loading same data from API on different Tab Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 tab fragments in my app, each meant to show different data from the same API URL (one call of 10 records).
**This is the final result im trying to achieve:**

**Tab 1:** Show records 1-5 from my API URL

**Tab 2:** Show records 6-10 from my API URL

**Tab 3:** Show different values from records 1-10

My goal is to load all this data in the first tab (**Tab1**) and show different results from the the JSON data returned in each tab as explained above.

**Progress so far:** Coded **Tab1** to show records 1-10.

**Need your help with:**

1. Make **Tab1** show records 1-5 and not all 10. *Since I want to load all 10 results in the same run and wont call the API multiple times, I don't wish to limit the number of results*.
2. Code **Tab2** show records 6-10 from the JSON DATA received in **Tab1**. *Means I need to communicate from Tab2 to my Tab1*

Hope to get direction for this, Thanks!

**What I've been thinking about:**

Setting 3 **static JSONOAdapters** and set it with the json result and use it for each tab. but..
Does **static JSON Adapters** will be a good solution or may cause memory problems?

Another problem: When I use this:

```
public void updateData(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        // update the adapter's dataset
        mJsonArray = jsonArray;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I get results 1-10, I have no idea how to limit it to the first 5 or results 6-10.

Answer (score 0):

Load data from 1 to 10 in your activity or fragment contains 2 fragments

After that add function setData for each fragment which data you want.

Last, go to your fragment and load data you set before.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load Data in your activity.
2. Initiate ViewPager Adapter and send Array of Items in the Constructor.

   ```
   public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter { 
   private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
   ArrayList<Item> arr; 


   public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,ArrayList<Item> arr) { 
       super(fragmentManager); 
       this.arr=arr;   
   } 

   // Returns total number of pages 
   @Override 
   public int getCount() { 
       return NUM_ITEMS;
   } 

   // Returns the fragment to display for that page 
   @Override 
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       switch (position) {
       case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment 
           return FirstFragment.newInstance(arr.subList(0,5)); 
       case 1: // Fragment # 1 
           return FirstFragment.newInstance(arr.subList(6,10)); 
       case 2: // Fragment # 2
           //Change your values according to you need then pass the arr in Frag 3
           return SecondFragment.newInstance(arr); 
       default: 
           return null; 
       } 
   } 

   // Returns the page title for the top indicator 
   @Override 
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       return "Page " + position;
   } 

   }
   ```

   3. Make static method in your Fragment to receive the array of items.